# The 'salt==3000.3' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Tags: salt-stack

I have upgraded my salt-master and now it doesn't start with following error :

```
avril 02 18:28:05 aksalt salt-master[1881]: Traceback (most recent call last):
avril 02 18:28:05 aksalt salt-master[1881]:   File "/usr/bin/salt-master", line 6, in <module>
avril 02 18:28:05 aksalt salt-master[1881]:     from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
avril 02 18:28:05 aksalt salt-master[1881]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3191, in <module>
avril 02 18:28:05 aksalt salt-master[1881]:     @_call_aside
avril 02 18:28:05 aksalt salt-master[1881]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3175, in _call_aside
avril 02 18:28:05 aksalt salt-master[1881]:     f(*args, **kwargs)
avril 02 18:28:05 aksalt salt-master[1881]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3204, in _initialize_master_working_set
avril 02 18:28:05 aksalt salt-master[1881]:     working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
avril 02 18:28:05 aksalt salt-master[1881]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 583, in _build_master
avril 02 18:28:05 aksalt salt-master[1881]:     ws.require(__requires__)
avril 02 18:28:05 aksalt salt-master[1881]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 900, in require
avril 02 18:28:05 aksalt salt-master[1881]:     needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
avril 02 18:28:05 aksalt salt-master[1881]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
avril 02 18:28:05 aksalt salt-master[1881]:     raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
avril 02 18:28:05 aksalt salt-master[1881]: pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'salt==3000.3' distribution was not found and is required by the application
avril 02 18:28:05 aksalt systemd[1]: salt-master.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

If any of you have a clue on that, that would really help!
Xavier

Answer (score 0):

Hi my solution was to completely reinstall salt-master & salt-minion purging all configuration documents..

Answer (score 0):

In the [latest CVE releases](https://saltproject.io/security_announcements/salt-security-advisory-release/) a breaking change was introduced and all previous releases were removed from the live repos.

If you still want 3000.3 you can get it from https://archive.repo.saltproject.io/.

Many people are questioning whether this policy is a good idea, on [this issue](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/61900) and a few others.